# Ошибка заключаеться в баге с текстом(показано на скриншоте) и в коде для высчитывание стипендий

Tags: c++

[image: баг с текстом]

[image: ошибка с высчитыванием стипендий]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void testCoeff(double a, double b, double c);
void printLinEqResult(double b, double c);
double calcLinRoot(double b, double c);
int calcSqrData(double a, double b, double c,
                double &re, double &im);
void printSqrEqResult(double a, double b, double c);
double calcStipendia(bool budget,
                    double grade, double art);
void testStipendia(bool budget, double grade,
                     double art);


int main() {
    // Налаштування для української мови
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    puts("\t Розробник Бойко М.О., гр.ПІ-231");
    puts("\t Дата народження 2006/08/14.");
    puts("\t Номер у списку групи 3.");
    puts("\n\t Лабораторна работа №4");
    puts("\t Завдання:1");
    puts("Реалізувати функції розв'язку квадратного рівняння\n"
         "та протестувати можливі варіанти");
    double a, b, c;
    testCoeff(0, 0, 0);
    testCoeff(0, 0, 4);
    testCoeff(1, 4, 5);
    testCoeff(1, 0, 0);



    puts("Введіть коефіцієнти: a=місяць народження,\n"
         " b = день народження, с = рік народження");
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    testCoeff(a,b,c);
    puts("Введіть рік народження з мінусом");
    cin >> c;
    testCoeff(a,b,c);
    puts("Завдання 2");
    puts("Реалізувати функцію для розрахунку стипендії\n"
         "та протестувати можливі варіанти");
         double y, o, r;
    testStipendia(false, 60.0, 1);
    testStipendia(false, 60.0, 0);
    testStipendia(false, 41.0, 0);
    testStipendia(true, 90.0, 0);
    testStipendia (true, 96.0, 0);

    puts("Введіть коефіцієнти: y=(бюджет-1, контракт-0),\n"
         " о = балл, r = борги");
    cin >> y >> o >> r;
    testStipendia(y, o, r);
    return 0;
}
void testCoeff(double a, double b, double c) {
    printf("a = %f, b = %f, c= %f\n",a, b, c);
    if (a == 0) {
        printLinEqResult(b, c);
    } else {
        printSqrEqResult(a, b, c);
    }
}
void printLinEqResult(double b, double c) {
    if( b != 0) {
        calcLinRoot(b, c);
    } else {
        if( c == 0) {
            puts("Лінійне рівняння");
            puts("Будь-яке рішення\n");
        } else {
            puts("Лінійне рівняння");
            puts("Коренів не має\n");
        }
    }
}
double calcLinRoot(double b, double c) {
    puts("Лінійне рівняння");
    return -c / b;
}
int calcSqrData(double a, double b, double c, double &re, double &im) {
    double D = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    if (D >= 0) {
        re = -b / (2 * a);
        im = sqrt(D) / (2 * a);
        return true;
    } else {
        re = -b / (2 * a);
        im = sqrt(abs(D)) / (2 * a);
        return false;
    }
}


void printSqrEqResult(double a, double b, double c) {
    double re, im;
    bool res = calcSqrData(a, b, c, re, im);

    if (res) {
        puts("Квадратне равняння");
        puts("Рівняння має дійсні корені:\n");
        cout << "x1 = " << re + im << endl;
        cout << "x2 = " << re - im << endl;
    } else {
        puts("Квадратне равняння");
        puts("Рівняння має комплексні корені:\n");
        cout << "x1 = " << re << " + " << im << "i" << endl;
        cout << "x2 = " << re << " - " << im << "i" << endl;
    }
}
double calcStipendia(bool budget,
                    double grade, double art){
double standartStipendia = 1000;
double boostStipendia =2000;
if(budget && grade >=75 && art == 0){
    if(grade >= 95){
        return boostStipendia;
    }
    else{
        return standartStipendia;
    }

}


}
void testStipendia(bool budget, double grade,
                     double art){
cout << "Студент на бюджеті: " << budget << endl;
cout << "Середній бал: " << grade << endl;
cout << "Заборгованості: " << art << endl;

    double Stip = calcStipendia(budget, grade, art);
    if (Stip > 0) {
        cout << "Розмір стипендії: " << Stip << " грн" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Студент не отримує стипендію" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Так может, это просто 0? округляйте до копеек...

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: если не выполнилось условие `if(budget && grade >=75 && art == 0)` то вы ничего не возвращаете. А это означает неопределённое поведение. Вы должны хоть что-то вернуть из функции.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Уже увидел свою ошибку, но все равно спасибо)